# NavigationDrawer в Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Добавил в проект стандартный Navigation Drawer Activity. В целом понял что к чему. Но не понял как реализовать переключение между Activity с его помощью. Из 4-х Activity в этом шаблоне, 3 из них непосредственно относятся к главному экрану. Но я не пойму, в проекте в котором будет много Activity, прейдется каждому Activity создавать по 3 новых xml файла? Выйдет уж очень много Xml. Или как нужно реализовать переход между экранами в приложении?

Answer (score 2):

1. Если все активити содержат одинаковый дровер, то нужен только один `xml` файл.
2. В каждой активити отображайте именно его
3. В зависимости от активити отображайте "нажатым" нужный пункт в меню.

Comment: Файл .java использует xml файл main.xml(в нем include NaviagationDrawer-a и остального); В этом main.xml, делается include ещё одного xml-a(content.xml), а этот content.xml содержит ещё один xml файл. Выходит такая матрешка в которой по сути 3-xml. Из этих 3-х xml, уникальной для каждой Activity будет одна. Выходит для каждой Activity буду делать copy-paste.